# Making component draggable in Angular10 TS project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I am trying to make a desktop-like environment where windows are draggable much like they are in your current OS. When I search for things like this I get a lot of Agular2 answers or some APIs that mainly talk about making a list reorderable with dragging. Some help in tackling this problem or direction for research would be much appreciated.

Comment: Angular is a framework that organizes and simplifies your code, but it stops short of giving you a specific way to setup a GUI. In other words, you're question is analogous to asking "I drive a Toyota, how should I get to Las Vegas?". I recommend looking at Konva for your GUI, here is a tutorial with Angular: https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-whiteboard-app-with-konva-and-angular-1e8f64e55412

Comment: I see, I was unaware of what I was unaware of haha. Thank you.